# R: converting original excel dates to the format yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, excel, date, timestamp, format

I've read an excel files with dates in different formats into R. Some are correctly read in the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS" and those who have had another format in excel before are now numbers like:
44586.727083333302 (stands for 25.01.2022  17:27:00)

I tried to convert them:

```
as.Date(df$dates, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', origin = "1900-01-01 24:00:00")
```

But R gives me just yyyy-mm-dd and HH:MM:SS is missing.

I need the timestamp as well. Does anyone know how the code must be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `as.POSIXct()` function instead of the `as.Date()` function. `as.Date()` returns the day without the time. The formatting you did should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Update: request OP:

You should install `parsedate` package:

[image]

```
library(parsedate)

#your df:
                 date
1 2018-06-30 12:09:34
2  44586.727083333302

# with this code:
dat %>% 
  mutate(x = parse_date(date))
```

you get this

```
                 date                   x
1 2018-06-30 12:09:34 2018-06-30 12:09:34
2  44586.727083333302 2022-07-31 15:39:06
```

**First answer:**
We could use the `convertDateTime` function:

```
library(openxlsx)

string <- 44586.727083333302
convertToDateTime(string, origin = "1900-01-01")

#or for your data frame:
convertToDateTime(df$dates, origin = "1900-01-01")

[1] "2022-01-25 17:27:00 CET"
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. Now I do have the problem though that I want to overwrite just a part of the data, because the other columns have already this format. When I try this:
df$dates[5391:6802] <- convertToDateTime(df$dates`[5391:6802], origin = "1900-01-01")
There are new numbers like 1643128020.. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: ? Do not understand. Could you please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing. Is it clear the way I described it now?

Comment: For the numbers like 1643128020 use this: `library(parsedate)
parse_date(1643128020)` Or provide a little mor info. Like some rows of the different numbers etc....

Comment: Unfortunately, my RStudio version can't load the parse_date package.
But here some more information about my code and data:
Right now up to column 5390 I do have this format for dates: 2018-06-30 12:09:34
Then from 5391 I have those numbers for dates 44586.7270
When I run this code: 
'convertToDateTime(df$dates[5391:6802], origin = "1900-01-01")' 
then it gives the correct format: 2021-10-09 18:04:00 CEST
But I want to overwrite those numbers like 44586.727083333302
When I try this by using this code:
df$dates[5391:6802] <- convertToDateTime(df$dates[5391:6802], origin = "1900-01-01")

Comment: Then I receive these numbers in my df : 1640346660

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Thank you for your update. Unfortunately it doesn't work or I have a mistake in my code. Is it dat = df?
df %>% 
  mutate(x = parse_date(dates))

then it goes over every variable and the ones that should be overwritten still are the same..